# Clarification on Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This may seen like an obvious question that could easily be answered by any Linear Algebra teacher, but unfortunately I do not has access to such a resource since I'm learning this on my own. Thus, I figured that this was the best place to get a clear answer. So, now on the to actual question.

From what I've read, Linear Independence is defined as follows: 
Let $V$ denote a vector space and $S = \{u_1, u_2, \dots,u_n\}$ be a subset of $V$. Then, $S$ is Linearly Independent if $$c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...+c_nu_n=0$$ while $c_i=0$.
However, nowhere can I find it explicitly stated that if $u_i$ are Linearly Independent, then they are orthogonal. I have assumed that to be the case. My thoughts are mainly supported by all diagrams of Linearly Independent vectors I have found.

Comment: No. The reverse implication holds, however.

Comment: What do you mean with orthogonal? You can talk about orthogonality only when is defined an inner product in your vector space. A set of vector could be linear indipendent while is a non-orthogonal set.

Comment: Linear independence is meaningful even when there is no inner product defined. In the plane, any two non zero vectors that do not lie on a line are linearly independent, and with the usual inner product, you can choose such points to be orthogonal or not (take $u_1=(1,0)^T, u_2=(1,1)^T$.

Comment: When I mentioned Orthagonal I was thinking of the Wikipedia Definition "In geometry, two Euclidean vectors are orthogonal if they are perpendicular, i.e., they form a right angle."

Comment: But an angle on an arbitrary vector space is defined by the inner product. Consider that the nicest examples for vector spaces are $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$ but the set of all continuous functions forms also a vector space. Or the set of bounded sequences. Und theses spaces have no inner product.

Comment: I think I get it. So, two vectors can be linearly independent, but not necessarily perpendicular? Also, vectors would be perpendicular if they also spanned the set, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I gave an example in an answer below for the case that there is an inner product. Like I mentioned, there are vector spaces where no angle can be defined.

Comment: At the introductory level the examples tend to be orthogonal, because they are easier to work with.  However, linear independence does not imply orthogonality.  As some point you will get to "Graham-Schmidt", which is an algorithm to convert a non-orthogonal basis to an orthogonal basis.

Answer (score 1):

We can just talk about orthogonal vectors if we have an inner product on the vector space. Therefore we consider first $V=\mathbb R^2$ with the standard inner product and $S=[u_1,u_2]\subset V$ where
$$
u_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }u_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $S$ is linear independent since 
$$
c_1u_1+c_2u_2=0\Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_1+c_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}\Leftrightarrow c_1=c_2=0.
$$
But $u_1$ and $u_2$ are not orthogonal since $\langle u_1,u_2\rangle = 1\neq 0$.

Now let be $V$ an arbitrary vector space with an inner product and $S=[u_1,\ldots,u_n]$ a subset of orthogonal vectors of $V$ which means $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle=0$ if $i\neq j$. Then starting with $c_1u_1+\ldots+c_nu_n=0$ yields
$$
0=\langle 0,u_i\rangle=\left\langle c_1u_1+\ldots+c_nu_n, u_i\right\rangle
=c_1\langle u_1,u_i\rangle+\ldots+c_n\langle u_n,u_i\rangle =c_i\langle u_i,u_i\rangle.
$$
This yields $c_i=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. Therefore $S$ is linear independent.

This shows that orthogonality is a stronger property than linear independence.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the way your definition of linear independence is stated. I would prefer the following: If $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$ and $S\subset V$, then $S$ is linearly independent if whenever $v_1,\dots,v_n\in S$ and $a_1,\dots,a_n\in F$, if
$$
a_1v_1+\dotsb+a_nv_n = 0,
$$
then $a_1=\dotsb=a_n=0$.

This does not mean that the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are *orthogonal*. For concreteness, if we consider the plane $\Bbb R^2$, then any two vectors that are not collinear constitute a linearly independent set, yet do not have to be orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly address your question, and is just a related aside too long for a comment, and it may confuse you more than it helps, but here goes.

First, to recap the other (more on-topic) answers:

**1.** Linear independence is a property inherent to sets of vectors in the vector space, *without any additional structure added to the vector space*.

**2.** Orthogonality is a property of sets of vectors in the vector space, *only when one puts* ***additional structure*** *onto the underlying vector space (i.e. a choice of inner product).*

**3.** Whether a set of linearly independent vectors is orthogonal ***depends on which inner product*** we have chosen to put onto the vector space.

**4.** Given ***any inner product***, if a set of vectors is orthogonal *with respect to that inner product*, then it follows that those vectors must be linearly independent (with respect to any inner product because, remember, linear independence is a property *inherent* to the *vector space itself*, without *any* choices of additional structure).

So this, perhaps, raises the question in your mind:

> Given a set of linearly independent vectors, can we find (and then choose) an inner product such that those vectors are orthogonal with respect to the ***chosen*** inner product?

The answer to this question turns out to be yes. A proof of this fact can be found on p.201 of Winitzki's [*Linear Algebra via the Exterior Product*](https://sites.google.com/site/winitzki/linalg), which is available (legally) for free online.

This might explain the reasoning behind authors drawing linearly independent vectors as perpendicular lines. Still, strictly speaking, this is incorrect in as much as it is only *sufficient*, ***not*** necessary, for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to represent perpendicular line segments in Euclidean space in order for them to be linearly independent.

Remember, the intuitive/layperson understanding of orthogonal, "perpendicular line segments" in geometry, corresponds to the *standard* choice of inner product for $\mathbb{R}^n$ -- but there are other types of vector spaces which can have inner products on them, and even for $\mathbb{R}^n$ there are other choices for the inner product which we can make other than the standard one.

<sub><sup>If one wants to get really technical and/or pedantic, symmetric to the answer to the question in yellow, it turns out that one can actually choose the isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and Euclidean space in such a way that *any* inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be used to represent the geometric structure of Euclidean space, but explaining that would be getting way off-topic.</sup></sub>